# How to add a same variable before every variable?

Tags: r

I have a Patient Data of 1 year. The original dataset includes patient's data which has 50 Variables such as record_id, age, race, lab test, HbA1c dates, values, etc. The sample dataset includes 10 columns - record_id, index_date, HbA1c_Date_1,HbA1c_1,HbA1c_Date_2,HbA1c_2, HbA1c_Date_3,HbA1c_3, HbA1c_Date_4, HbA1c_4. The record ID is Unique to everyone. Each Patient has visited the clinic multiple times. Whenever the patient visited their HbA1c count was taken. HbA1c_Date_1 is the first date of the visit. HbA1c_Date_2 is the second date of the visit.

The Sample Dataset -

```
structure(list(record_id = c("134844", "134845", "122062", "134846", "110934", "12345","13456", "17890", "190078", "181234", "15843", "18790", "12675"), 
               index.date = c("8/16/2018", "3/28/2019", "2/14/2019", "8/1/2018","8/1/2018", "8/2/2018", "10/4/2018", "6/19/2019", "12/5/2018", "8/23/2018", "3/12/2020", "8/18/2018", "3/10/2020"),
               HbA1c_Date_1 = c("10/2/2019", "8/28/2019", "7/19/2019", "7/10/2019", "4/2/2019", "10/15/2019", "12/4/2019", "10/2/2019",  "2/12/2019", "5/7/2019", "9/11/2019", "5/8/2019", "2/6/2019"),
              HbA1c_1= c("6.6", "8.6", "6.1", "6.9", "10.5", "6.3", "5.5", "5.2", "6.2", "5.7", "5.3", "5.1", "5.4"),
              HbA1c_Date_2 = c("3/5/2019", "10/19/2019", "NA", "3/25/2020", "6/24/2019", "1/9/2019", "11/1/2019", "NA", "12/13/2018", "NA", "NA", "5/26/2020", "5/9/2019"),
              HbA1c_2 = c("7.9", "6.7", "NA", "6.7", "7", "5.8", "5.6", "NA", "6.6", "NA", "NA", "5", "5.5"),
              HbA1c_Date_3 = c("10/8/2019", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1/8/2020", "10/30/2019", "NA", "NA", "3/13/2019", "NA", "NA", "11/23/2019"),
              HbA1c_3 = c("6", "NA", "NA", "NA", "7.5", "5.8", "NA", "NA", "6.6", "NA", "NA", "NA", "5.7"),
              HbA1c_Date_4 = c("1/24/2020","NA", "NA", "NA","NA", "NA", "NA","NA","8/2/2019", "NA","NA", "NA", "2/29/2020"),
              HbA1c_4 = c("7.6", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "6.6", "NA", "NA", "NA", "5.6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

I want to include "#Days" variable before every "HbA1c_Date_" column. So the output must look like this.

| Record_ID | Index.date | #Days | HbA1c_Date_1 | #Days | HbA1c_Date_2 | HbA1c_2 | #Days | Hba1c_Date_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

and so on.

I tried using the names() function but it did not work.

```
> # Get the column names of the dataset
column_names <- names(dataraw)

# Loop through the column names
for (i in seq_along(column_names)) {
  if (grepl("^HbA1c_Date_", column_names[i])) {
    # Add "days" before the current hba1c_date_ variable
    new_name <- c("days", column_names[i])
    
    # Update the column names
    names(dataraw)[i:(i+1)] <- new_name
  }
}
```

Comment: What is supposed to be in the `days` (or `#Days`) column? is it all `NA`?

Comment: I don't see the date in `HbA1c_Date_1` column

Comment: @jkatam Opps! I have updated it.

Comment: could you please check the updated code, the code will have new variables that start with the name `new`

Comment: @BenBolker So, actually I want to calculate the difference between "index.date" and each "HbA1c_Date_" in months in the "days" column.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the data provided here the code

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(record_id = c("134844", "134845", "122062", "134846", "110934", "12345","13456", "17890", "190078", "181234", "15843", "18790", "12675"), 
               index.date = c("8/16/2018", "3/28/2019", "2/14/2019", "8/1/2018","8/1/2018", "8/2/2018", "10/4/2018", "6/19/2019", "12/5/2018", "8/23/2018", "3/12/2020", "8/18/2018", "3/10/2020"),
               HbA1c_Date_1 = c("10/2/2019", "8/28/2019", "7/19/2019", "7/10/2019", "4/2/2019", "10/15/2019", "12/4/2019", "10/2/2019",  "2/12/2019", "5/7/2019", "9/11/2019", "5/8/2019", "2/6/2019"),
               HbA1c_1= c("6.6", "8.6", "6.1", "6.9", "10.5", "6.3", "5.5", "5.2", "6.2", "5.7", "5.3", "5.1", "5.4"),
               HbA1c_Date_2 = c("3/5/2019", "10/19/2019", "NA", "3/25/2020", "6/24/2019", "1/9/2019", "11/1/2019", "NA", "12/13/2018", "NA", "NA", "5/26/2020", "5/9/2019"),
               HbA1c_2 = c("7.9", "6.7", "NA", "6.7", "7", "5.8", "5.6", "NA", "6.6", "NA", "NA", "5", "5.5"),
               HbA1c_Date_3 = c("10/8/2019", "NA", "NA", "NA", "1/8/2020", "10/30/2019", "NA", "NA", "3/13/2019", "NA", "NA", "11/23/2019",'NA'),
               HbA1c_3 = c("6", "NA", "NA", "NA", "7.5", "5.8", "NA", "NA", "6.6", "NA", "NA", "NA", "5.7"),
               HbA1c_Date_4 = c("1/24/2020","NA", "NA", "NA","NA", "NA", "NA","NA","8/2/2019", "NA","NA", "NA", "2/29/2020"),
               HbA1c_4 = c("7.6", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "6.6", "NA", "NA", "NA", "5.6")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))





df2 <- map_df(df,\(x)ifelse(x=='NA', NA_character_,x))

df3 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(across(c(index.date,HbA1c_Date_1,HbA1c_Date_2,HbA1c_Date_3,HbA1c_Date_4), ~ifelse(is.na(.x),NA_real_,lubridate::mdy(.x)))) %>%
  mutate(across(c(HbA1c_Date_1,HbA1c_Date_2,HbA1c_Date_3,HbA1c_Date_4), ~.x-index.date, .names = 'new_{col}'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 13 × 13
   record_id index.date HbA1c_Date_1
   <chr>          <dbl> <chr>       
 1 134844         17759 7.9         
 2 134845         17983 6.7         
 3 122062         17941 <NA>        
 4 134846         17744 6.7         
 5 110934         17744 7           
 6 12345          17745 5.8         
 7 13456          17808 5.6         
 8 17890          18066 <NA>        
 9 190078         17870 6.6         
10 181234         17766 <NA>        
11 15843          18333 <NA>        
12 18790          17761 5           
13 12675          18331 5.5         
# ℹ 10 more variables: HbA1c_1 <chr>,
#   HbA1c_Date_2 <dbl>, HbA1c_2 <chr>,
#   HbA1c_Date_3 <dbl>, HbA1c_3 <chr>,
#   HbA1c_Date_4 <dbl>, HbA1c_4 <chr>,
#   new_HbA1c_Date_2 <dbl>,
#   new_HbA1c_Date_3 <dbl>,
#   new_HbA1c_Date_4 <dbl>
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so  much for the code, but unfortunately the code is not working. I am getting an error.

Comment: Please let me know the error so i can update

Comment: This is the error- Error in `recycle_columns()`:
! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
• Size 12: Column `HbA1c_Date_3`.
• Size 13: Columns `record_id`, `index.date`, `HbA1c_Date_1`, `HbA1c_1`,
  `HbA1c_Date_2`, and 4 more.
ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.

Comment: ok this is the issue with your data, if you check your data there are onlt 12 elements or values in `HbA1c_Date_3`, please add an additional element as `NA` in the last to `HbA1c_Date_3` and check the code execution

Comment: I have added an extra "NA" to HbA1c_Date_3 but it did not help. After executing the code when I View it, it just disrupted my data. Many of the columns are empty. I got an error too- "Caused by warning:
! All formats failed to parse. No formats found." Wish I could send you a screenshot.

Comment: Here in the answer I updated to include the `data` please copy the data and code and run and check